# TypeError: 'BlockManager' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, cudf

I'm trying to merge a cudf dataframe and a geopandas dataframe.

```
df = df.merge(parishes[['NAME_3', 'area']], left_on='Parish', right_on='NAME_3').drop(columns=['NAME_3'])
```

`df` is a cudf dataframe and `parishes` is a geopandas dataframe.

On running the above line, I get the below error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-5143535bcf20> in <module>()
----> 1 df = df.merge(parishes[['NAME_3', 'area']], left_on='Parish', right_on='NAME_3').drop(columns=['NAME_3'])

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cudf/core/join/join.py in _validate_merge_params(lhs, rhs, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, how, suffixes)
    414 
    415         # If nothing specified, must have common cols to use implicitly
--> 416         same_named_columns = set(lhs._data) & set(rhs._data)
    417         if (
    418             not (left_index or right_index)

TypeError: 'BlockManager' object is not iterable
```

What is the problem ? Can someone help me with this ? This is the first time I'm using cudf dataframes, so I am not sure what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

`cudf` and `geopandas` aren't compatible with one another (yet). You should be able to move all of the non-geometry columns in your geopandas dataframe into `cudf` using, for example, `gpu_df = cudf.from_pandas(df[['Parishes', 'name_3']])`, then you can merge that gpu_df with any other `cudf` DataFrame. cudf doesn't have `geometry` datatypes on its roadmap currently, but `cuspatial` (https://github.com/rapidsai/cuspatial), which depends directly on `cudf`, does. When 21.06 releases in June  `cuspatial` will have support for `geometry` columns and make it easier for you to use all the power of `cudf` and `cuspatial` with anything from geopandas.